# button display on fixed header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap fixed hear. I would like to add a button for logout. When i added ,it is warping in second line. Is there anaywa we can move it to the same line of fixed hear but right most corner ?

Here is fiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bmarsh123/tK4f6/2/)

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>            
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info col-md-1 col-md-offset-10">Log Out</button>                    
    </div>        
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `col-md` classes and add `navbar-btn` and `navbar-right`. Also you need to move the button into the `nav-collapse`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/Ac4UE/3/)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right">Log Out</button>
```

Comment: Thanky you ver much sir! :)